# threshold() Please input the valid canvas or img id error

Tags: javascript, opencv

I have a problem with `cv.threshold()` function in **opencv.js** library.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="opencv.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Hello OpenCV.js</h2>
<p id="status">OpenCV.js is loading...</p>
<div>
  <div class="inputoutput">
    <img id="imageSrc" alt="No Image" />
    <div class="caption">imageSrc <input type="file" id="fileInput" name="file" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="inputoutput">
    <canvas id="canvasInput" ></canvas>    
  </div>
    <div class="inputoutput2">
    <canvas id="canvasOutput" ></canvas>
   </div>
  </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
let image1=cv.imread('bookpage.jpg');
let threshold;
cv.threshold(image1,threshold,12,250,THRESH_BINARY);
cv.imshow('canvasInput',image);
cv.imshow('canvasOutput',threshold);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Error:

> Uncaught Error: Please input the valid canvas or img id.
>       at Object.Module.imread (/C:/Users/q/Desktop/web/opencv.js/4-)Thresholding/opencv.js:56:20361)

How can I fix that error?

Comment: Where is `'bookpage.jpg'` located? Does the path need to be [relative or absolute?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing))

Comment: bookpage.jpg and index.html are located in same directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass in a canvas or image ID as stated in the error message. You're passing it a file name. Sample code from the docs

[OpenCV docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d0/d84/tutorial_js_usage.html)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
let imgElement = document.getElementById('imageSrc');
 let inputElement = document.getElementById('fileInput');
inputElement.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  imgElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
}, false);
imgElement.onload = function() {
  let mat = cv.imread(imgElement);
  cv.imshow('canvasOutput', mat);
  mat.delete();
};
function onOpenCvReady() {
   document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'OpenCV.js is ready.';
}
</script>
```